# best way to send friend a card through FB app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I have an app that allows users to construct a personal card with a message, photo, song, etc. for an occasion (birthday being just one example).  You can check it out here:  apps.facebook.com/getmixxd

I was using graph api to allow the sender to post to recipient's wall with the option to make it public or private.  As of Feb 5th this functionality is disabled apparently.

My question is what is my best alternative?  Just using the dialog box doesn't seem to solve the problem because one of the features users asked for was ability to specify when the card was delivered (my friend's birthday is tomorrow, but I want to construct the card today and have it delivered tomorrow).  Also, none of the preset custom actions appear to apply.

Looking for some advice from FB gurus on what my best option is...

Thanks!!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not an FB Guru, and this is also problem of mine.

Here's what I've repeatedly seeing for the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15234553

Your best bet is the Open Graph API, which is you have to submit an Application for and "action" an a corresponding "object" for that. For example action "cook" and object "recipe".