# Facebook graph API wall post alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been using a class based on Hernan Amiune's library for the Facebook graph API to allow website user's to write to their friends walls from my code. With the recent February changes the Graph API method to do this is no longer available.

Apparently I need to use the Feed Dialogue now, but can I call this from c# code? Does anyone have a sample or an alternative I can use?

In short can I write to someone's wall on behalf of another user using server side code only.

Comment: you can, i have provided u the link. download the library and you will be able to do it.

Comment: Thanks Parminder, I can't seem to see the link though

Comment: I don't think this is possible anymore since Facebook wants the user to ultimately click on the "post" button. I ran into the same issue and I had to use "Send Dialog".

Comment: here is the link Blatfrig, http://blog.impact-works.com/2011/07/12/posting-to-facebook-wall-in-asp-netc-using-graph-apipart-5/

Comment: Can I ask why my answer was deleted ? Using the code set I mentioned in my answer, a user can post on his/friends wall. I have used the codes few months ago.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone it is pretty clear that the graph API can't be used to write on a friend's wall anymore. But no-one has yet given an answer on whether (or how) I can call the feed dialogue from C# code and use that instead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *In short can I write to someone's wall on behalf of another user using server side code only?*

As of the [February 6 breaking changes](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/), you can no longer post to a user's friends' wall via the Graph API. This means you can't write on someone's wall on behalf of another user in any code language or SDK. You either have to use the Feed Dialog or use Mention Tagging or Action Tagging.

#### From the Facebook Developer Roadmap:

> Stories that include friends via user [mentions tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/) or [action tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingpeople/) will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Feed Dialogue info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) which details a nice simple javascript example and even simpler a direct url example, to convert either to utilise C# seems an extremely trivial task.

See [A related answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14792062/posting-to-friends-wall-with-graph-api-via-feed-connection-failing-since-feb)

Comment: Thanks Paul. You've effectively restated my question. The direct URL example you refer to is lacking in detail and I can't see a way of using it to write to someone else's wall.

Comment: I saw the related post a few days back, but it still only tells me what I can already gather from the facebook developer site

Comment: The drop down list next to the share button allows the post to go to all friends or a customised list etc. Or you could specify a userid in the to: parameter in javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately the share button is of no use. I want to do this in server side code.

Comment: Ah then I suggest a little reverse engineering of the library you used, for feed dialogue they say "Your application can also publish directly to a profile's feed without user interaction, use the corresponding Graph API call.", at first glance in their graph api equivalent that it's just the URL that's changed for a POST.

Comment: That's exactly what i initially thought so I tried it, but could only get a non-specific error back.